# How to get blocked contact details list in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am having an app that require me to access the contact list on my iOs device. Is there is a way to get the list of blocked contacts on my device and not the simulator

Comment: why downvote? it's a good question. if someone with 10k+ reps would have asked the same, it would receive upvotes...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Apple do not provide any public API to access this data.

So, as far as I know, there is no way to do so (unless you work with jailbroken devices).